# Listing on Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

So I am interested in making a list from {10,11,12,1,2,3,4,5) which actually represents months from {October, November,...May} of the following year. However I keep getting a list error. Is there actually a better way of writing this script. Find code below

```
var list = ee.List.sequence(10, 5);
print(list, 'FromOct2000-May2001')
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first make the list from 10 to 12 and then the list from 1 to 5 and simply concatenate them using `cat`.

```
var list = ee.List.sequence(10, 12).cat(ee.List.sequence(1, 5));
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jonathan. It worked!